# In Ubuntu Bash WSL in Windows 10, how can I have my redis-server service start?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Ubuntu Bash installed on Windows 10. How do I have `redis-server` start up in the background without having to run `sudo service redis-server restart` each time I initially open a terminal?

I tried adding that command to my `~/.bashrc` file, but that causes me to have to enter my password each time I open a terminal window.  It also restarts the server every time I open a terminal window.  Does anyone know of a better way of me handling this?

Comment: No clue about WSL but it sounds like your problem is caused by sudo requiring a password, so you can call visudo and set nopasswd: https://askubuntu.com/questions/334318/sudoers-file-enable-nopasswd-for-user-all-commands, second part, does that write service write a PID file? If so you can check if it exists and if so check if the process exists before you start the service.

Comment: Dose the service run in background after closing CMD window? Type `service xyz start` and close the CMD window. You may see that service is running in task manager. Which Windows version are you running?

Comment: I'm running Windows 10 Pro Build 1803. I do believe it's running in the background after I close the terminal, because it works after closing out all of the terminals.

Comment: @TNierath, seems like I'd have to write a bash script.  I can check and try to do it that way, but might take me a bit.  I ever write bash scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I use this for starting `sshd` once upon login to termux on android, your problem sounds very similar.  If your process creates a `.pid` file then it should be easy to replace ssh with your server binary and copy everything into `.bashrc`

```bash
# check if pid file exists in path (termux path), if so,
#   check if process id is still running, if so,
#     do nothing
# otherwise start sshd

if [ ! -f $HOME/../usr/var/run/ssh.pid ] \
       || ps|grep $(cat $HOME/../usr/var/run/ssh.pid)
then
    sshd
fi
```